# How to make one CPU to be used simulataneously be three different users

Tags: virtualization

As a bootstrapping start-up we are thinking of saving on the IT hardware cost by making more use of the hardware that we have.

As a solopreneur I have a laptop config : intel core2duo processor, 3Gb RAM and 250 GB HDD.
Now we are planning to increase our team to 3 members. Will like your suggestions on the nest cost-effective step that I can take so that I can use the computing power of the existing laptop to act as a kind of server and then buy to more monitors where the new recruits can do the daily work on and they need to have different login id and access and they dont need access to all the files/applications as are available in my laptop. We use internet intensively to do our day to day activity.

Please share you experience, whether you think this is a good ploy or there is any other more effective way of achieving the same result.

Comment: I could understand this with server hardware but a laptop!? Seriously, just buy some hardware and quit being cheap!

Comment: If you were employing carpenters, would you have them share the same hammer ?

Comment: @Earlz: We are not all rich Americans. In many countries, labour is relatively much cheaper than hardware.

Comment: @Thomas yes I'm aware but I mean even buying netbooks would be better than such a thing. You can usually get junk hardware for free or cheap and if you're comfortable with Unix-based OSs then you can use your favorite Linux/BSD(which has way lower system requirements than windows). But this 3 people sharing a laptop somehow will not work..

Comment: Well, hooking up cheap netbooks as "smart terminals" sounds like an excellent answer to this question :)

Comment: In any case, doesn't this belong on SuperUser?

Comment: @Thomas yes that would work, but with 3 people on the laptop how do you think that the netbook hardware itself won't be faster?

Comment: Perhaps you could have the additional team members write their code on paper.  One team member could act as the "key puncher", and type all of the code into the computer.  He could print out the compilation errors, and the other team members could go back to their desks and make the corrections on paper.

Comment: @Gilbert.. please.. just no.

Comment: It's unclear what the exact specifications of your laptop are, if you are on the cheap way you can forget about three sets of applications (IDE + Documentation + Browser + Mail) to run at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

As a minimum you have to connect three monitors to the laptop. Right? I never saw laptops with more than two video-outputs. So at least you'll need some piece of external hardware to make connection possible at all. Such hardware [isn't free](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/three-monitors-for-every-user.html) even for desktop systems. I don't think that you'll find something cheaper than buying two additional low-end desktops.

- After all, the day is long, split it in three parts, 8 hours each.
- Take a look at [pair programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming)
- Ask for help from FFF (Friends, Family and Fools)

Comment: +1: Best idea in this situation: program in shifts, or program in groups. Splitting 1 laptop 3 ways leaves 3 people without enough computer to get their work done.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with the other commenters that this is probably a very bad idea, especially for the computer you're talking about.  That said, there's products like the [Aten CS231](http://www.aten.com/products/productItem.php?pcid=2005010513171002&psid=20070130133751001&pid=20061115161843001&layerid=subClass2) that do "computer sharing", allowing multiple monitors, keyboards, and mice to be hooked to a single PC and have multiple simultaneous users on a single system.  I know that 3-say sharing devices exist, but I'm having trouble digging up a product name.

I still can't stress enough that by the time you've gone this far, you're not far off money-wise from just purchasing a few cheap desktop systems.